# Geodesics meeting with angle $0$ in ${\rm CAT}(0)$ space

Tags: metric-geometry

Consider two distinct geodesics $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ in a CAT($0$) space, issued from the same base point.
A trivial example where we have $\angle(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)=0$ is when
$\gamma_1(t) = \gamma_2(t)$ for $t$ smaller than some $\varepsilon > 0$. In this case, I say that they define the same germ.

My question is, **is there examples of CAT(0) spaces with geodesics meeting with angle 0 and every geodesic is non-branching** ?

The only class of examples I know of non-branching geodesics meeting with angle $0$ are constructed as follow:
consider the following subset of the Euclidian plane, with induced length-metric,
$X = \{ (x,y); 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le x^2 \}$. It is a CAT(0) space,
the geodesic between $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ is the segment and the geodesic between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ is the arc of parabola. These geodesics meet at $(0,0)$ with angle $0$ and they don't define the same germ.

However, in this space there exist branching geodesics, for example
the geodesic between $(0,0)$ and $(1, t)$ for $t>0$ all define the same germ.

**Edit**: I add a description of these geodesics. The geodesic from $(0,0)$ to
$(1,t)$ is an arc of parabola from $(0,0)$ to $P$ concatenated with the segment $[P, (1,t)]$ where $P$ is the point on the parabola closest to the origin such that the segment $[P, (1,t)]$ lies in $X$.

Comment: Why they define the same germ? If your space is $CAT(0)$ they vary continuously with their endpoints.

Comment: @DanteGrevino they do vary continuously. The geodesic between $(0,0)$ and $(1, t)$ follows the arc of parabola for some time and then is a segment.

Comment: @ Florentin MB : Could you explain "branching" ?

Comment: @HKLee Two geodesics are branching when they are distinct but define the same germ

Answer (score 1):

Consider an arc $x=0,\ (y-1)^2+z^2=1,\ 0<y\leq 1,\ z>0$. When we
rotate it wrt $z$-zxis, then we have $X$, homeomorphic to a disc
with a hole.

Note that it has a nonpositive
curvature. A completion of universal cover of $X$ is homeomorphic to
$\bigcup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}\ [oc(t)]$ where $c:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow
\mathbb{S}^2$ is an immersion, $o$ is origin, and $[ab]$ is a line segment in
$\mathbb{E}^3$.

Geodesics with Angle $0$ : Assume that $$p=(0,1-\cos\ \theta,\ast),\
q=(0,-1+\cos\ \theta
,\ast)\in X$$

Now consider a completion of $X$ : $|p-o|=\theta =|q-o|$. And $|p-q|
< \pi(1-\cos\ \theta )$.